# Javascript for-loop async File execution

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

In the next code, I want to process several files at the same time without wait to the end of each other. For this reason, I first read the files (array) and then the callback is called to process an element of this array instance.

I have found a problem into this javascript code, exactly in a async for-loop, where this process is executed as a sync code instead of async.

```
var array = ['string1','string2','string3','string4'];

function processArray (arrayString,callback){
    //Read file Example.csv thought sync way
    try{
        var ifs = new InputFileStream('Example.csv','utf8');
        table = ifs.read(0);
        ifs.close();
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.stack);
    }

    callback(arrayString, table);

}

//Async for
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {                
    processArray(array[i], function(arrayString, table){
        //Here process the file values thought async way
        console.log('processed_'+i);
    });
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this construction is supposed to behave asynchronously?

Comment: I guess that this example is the right way to implement a for-loop async. Do you know any other method to do it?

Comment: What I was hinting at is that this isn't async. What makes you think it is?

Comment: Could you show me the async way of this for-loop?

Comment: what is `InputFileStream` - not standard javascript that I know

Comment: As you said that __Read file Example.csv thought sync way__ is what `InputFileStream` does, it blocks the thread and, unless the function is complete, your for-loop won't do next iteration.

Comment: Yes, the code reads the example.csv file thought sync way, and that isn't a problem, but the callback is also processed in sync way, when I need the async process to this method because its execution time is so long.

Comment: Put the call back in a setTimeout with a delay of 1ms. That will run it in the next block of execution and your loop will continue on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the call back in a setTimeout with a delay of 1ms. That will run it in the next block of execution and your loop will continue on.

e.g. use this:

```
setTimeout(function() { callback(arrayString, table); }, 1);
```

instead of this:

```
callback(arrayString, table);
```

An alternative to this is to run the callback on a separate thread using Web Workers. I don't think it would appropiate to provide a long answer describing how to do multi threaded JavaScript here so I'll just leave the link to the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 0):

> where this process is executed as a sync code instead of async

I've seen that you just have find out the answers of your question, remember that JavaScript is **single thread**.

So, for that when you execute operations that require full use of CPU like for..loops, while, etc; you just will get your code running synchronous and not only that,

> You will get your **web page freeze** if they are huge loops

Let me give you an example, this is a while loop that will run for 6 seconds, look how you cannot do anything in `stackoverflow`.

```js
function blocker (ms) {
    console.log('You cannot do anything')
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(true) {
        if (new Date().getTime() > now +ms)
            return;
    }   
}
blocker(6000) //This stop your entire web page for 6 seconds
```

If you really want to achieve running blocking code in the background read about [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) or you just can use a small library I wrote, that allow you to execute a blocking CPU function in the background, I called it **[GenericWebWorker](https://github.com/fercarvo/GenericWebWorker)**